# Detect Bump On Bottom Of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-motion, motion

I have been doing a lot of research in the area of an iPhone's magnetometer, gyroscope and accelerometer, but can't seem to a good conclusion.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Acceleration in one direction to detect a stop. (Always detected when person is holding phone, and seems to just move in that direction)
2. Gyroscope angle changing directions regarding the way in which a person is holding the device. (Not consistent because trying to get shake to work with this as well)
3. Bump API/Existing Code (Does not work)

**Has anyone come across a solid solution for detecting a tap on the bottom of and iPhone, against an object? Preferably with sample code.**

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937867/detect-when-an-iphone-has-been-bumped?rq=1

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082685/coremotion-bump-vs-shake-on-iphone?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/motionkit-the-missing-ios-coremotion-wrapper-written-in-swift-99fcb83355d0#.vxwbnebdv) is what you are looking for? It's a set of custom wrappers around the hardware that is designed specifically for detecting "accidents", which sounds like what you're looking for.